# error generate certification with jsrsasign

Tags: javascript, ssl, rsa, digital-signature, pem

i use jsrsasign to verify signature, and i try to generate a signature but i get this error :
[**Uncaught init failed:malformed PKCS8 private key(code:004)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rixg5.png)
maybe because i just have the **pem certificate key**

is there a solution how to get the **private key** from the **pem certificate key**
or how can i resolve this error

```html
// initialize
var sig = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({"alg": "SHA1withRSA"});
// initialize for signature generation
sig.init(pemCertificate);   // rsaPrivateKey of RSAKey object
// update data
sig.updateString('aaa')
// calculate signature
var sigValueHex = sig.sign()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a jsrsasign maintainer. There is no way to extract a private key from a public key certificate. To sign certificate, you need a private key.